# Wordpress content invisible

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, webfonts, invisible

I've a problem with a wordpress site. Out of no reason the text of a post disappears or is invisible in the frontend. As soon as you zoom out and in the text is showing! This is a problem my friend is reporting to me. I wasn't able to cause this issue by myself. I've cleared the cache and used Safari, Chrome and Firefox in the private mode as well as my friend did. For me it still sounds like a browser issue or do I miss something with this issue? I would like to give you an example but as I said I coudn't cause this issue by myself. Could it be something else except the browser he is using?

**EDIT**

transitionally I fixed it with this quick n dirty jQuery right above the `wp_footer` and the `</body>` tag.

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 jQuery(function() { jQuery('body').hide().show(); });
</script>`

related to this post [google group](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/elw8busIfJA/_X01ICU8LVMJ)

If anybody has a better approach please let me know.

Comment: What browser is he using? Does he have any other browsers he can test it in to see if the same thing occurs?

Comment: He uses Chrome version 33.0.1750.117 and I've a similar version. I told him the same to use Firefox or Safari to see if the same issue occurs. So you think as well that it's a browser issue?

Comment: It could an extension, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193834/aside-disappear-suddenly-never-seen-this-issue

Comment: I tried this with AdBlock Plus but Firefox still works. But I just figured out that in Chrome and private mode I can cause the issue by myself. As soon as I change any css value or if I size down the browser window manually the text appears. See [here](http://www.feierfee.de/tipp-reiterparty-vol-9/)

Comment: I also tried this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984543/google-chrome-bug-website-not-displaying-text) but it didn't worked